# How to fire an ActionListener when a page is loaded?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Working with JSF 2.0 (and Primefaces), is there a way to fire an ActionListener when a page is loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends of your need, for example you can use `f:event` with `preRenderView` if you want to initliaze something in your bean:

Check this link :
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/

But you should know that the event is call on every requests : ajax, validation fail .... You can check if it's new request like this:

```
public boolean isNewRequest() {
        final FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        final boolean getMethod = ((HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getMethod().equals("GET");
        final boolean ajaxRequest = fc.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest();
        final boolean validationFailed = fc.isValidationFailed();
        return getMethod && !ajaxRequest && !validationFailed;
    }
```